# Error parsing JSON value

Tags: android, json, jsonexception

I received the error: JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Success of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject at success = json.getBoolean(SUCCESS);

I searched around SO and the Internet and I am still not understanding what I am doing wrong.

My JSON looks like: Success

```
  @Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Log.v("LoginActivity", "UserLoginTask-AsyncTask-doinBackground");
    Boolean success;
    String username = mUsernameView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    try {

        //Building Parameters
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", mUsernameView.getText().toString()));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mPasswordView.getText().toString()));

        Log.d("request!", "starting");

        //getting product details by making HTTP request
        //JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL, "POST", postParameters);
        //Error parsing data org.json.JSONException:
        //Value Success of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

        String response = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL, "POST", postParameters);
        Log.v("SUCCESS", SUCCESS.toString());

        // Log.v("json", json.toString()); //null
        //success = json.getBoolean(SUCCESS);

        //if (success == true) {
        if (response.toLowerCase().contains("success")) {
            // Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
            Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
            //return json.getBoolean(FAILURE);
        } else {
            //Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(FAILURE));
             Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Login Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
        }
         } catch (JSONException e) { //error here
         e.printStackTrace();
         }

        return null;
    }
}

public String makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                Log.v("makeHttpRequest client", httpClient.toString());
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                Log.v("makeHttpRequest post", httpPost.toString());
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.v("makeHttpRequest is", is.toString());

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                   // is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, HTTP.UTF_8), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.v("json=sb", sb.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return json;

    }
```

Comment: Show error log or response which getting from server in `Log.v("json", json.toString());` line

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ or Android Studio, try setting a breakpoint at the `success = json.getBoolean(SUCCESS);` line and test the JSON in the local console.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Null pointer exception since the makeHttpRequest cannot be completed since Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Success of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: where is you json data?

Comment: @JohnWilliams: any issue in showing json data or full error log ?

Comment: @JohnWilliams: i think problem is due to ` Log.v("json", json.toString());` line because `json` is `null` try it as `Log.v("json", "JSONObject ::"json);` and check what you are getting in log

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I removed the logging as a whole and am getting null at success = json.getBoolean(SUCCESS);. Please see update. Could this error have to do with the JSON Object's configuration?

Comment: @JohnWilliams: Agree getting NPE  because `json` is `null`. add logs inside `makeHttpRequest` method and check what getting from server

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Does agree mean that you believe his error have to do with the JSON Object's configuration? And updated.

Comment: @JohnWilliams: please add log for `json = sb.toString();` line in `makeHttpRequest` method and check what getting from server and if possible please share latest logs with us

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Updated. json = sb.toString() has a value of Success

Comment: @JohnWilliams: see my answer probably help you in fixing issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in log:

> Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Success of
>   type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Means not getting `JSONObject` from server but just getting `Success` String as response from server.

So, no need to convert `json` to `JSONObject`. do following change to get it work :

**1.** Change return type of `makeHttpRequest` method to `String` and return `json`(remove or comment `jObj = new JSONObject(json);` line )

**2.** In `doInBackground` call `makeHttpRequest` method as:

```
String response = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL,
                                            "POST", 
                                             postParameters);
if(response.toLowerCase().contains("success")){
  /// do task
}else{
  // do task
}
```

Comment: @JohnWilliams: try my answer and let me know result

Comment: Exception 'org.json.JSONException' is never thrown in the corresponding try block. Updated.

Comment: Updated. The code will not run because Error:(334, 20) error: exception JSONException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement at catch (JSONException e)

Comment: @JohnWilliams: dude also remove try-catch block from `makeHttpRequest` in which `jObj = new JSONObject(json);` line wrapped

Comment: @JohnWilliams: ok change `JSONException` to `Exception`

Comment: Thanks for everything!